# wrong width in mozilla firefox [ site with bootstrap]

Tags: css, width

[first in chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/85BcF.png)

[second in mozilla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPFMC.png)

```css
.card {
    flex-direction: row;
    position: relative;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -ms-flex-direction: column;
    flex-direction: column;
    min-width: 0;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    background-clip: border-box;
}
.about img {
    width: 30%;
    border: 3px solid #1596C7;
}

.card-body {
    flex: 1 1 auto;
    padding: 1.25rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="card d-flex">       
                    <img src="" class="card-img-top  rounded-circle">
                    
                    <div class="card-body ml-sm-4">
                    </div>
 </div>
```

i tried to make a div for image but not working.

and one interesting thing is that in responsive, when the parent div has flex-direction: column instead of row,  everything works fine.

Comment: Welcome to SO @Juba please post a minimal working code so that we can help you...

Comment: i changed flex:1 1 auto to 1 1 0 and it works !

Comment: Glad you solved it yourself. Cheers!